# Configure Automysqlbackup for MariaDB

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, backup, ubuntu-20.04

I try to backup my databases with Automysqlbackup. I'm using MariaDB 10.3. I set username and password for root user in MariaDB and also configured Automysqlbackup configuration file in `/etc/default/automysqlbackup`

Here is some of my Automysqlbackup configuration

```
# Username to access the MySQL server e.g. dbuser
#USERNAME=`grep user /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | tail -n 1 | cut -d"=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`
USERNAME=tutor_db

# Username to access the MySQL server e.g. password
#PASSWORD=`grep password /etc/mysql/debian.cnf | tail -n 1 | cut -d"=" -f2 | awk '{print $1}'`
PASSWORD=rootpassword

# Host name (or IP address) of MySQL server e.g localhost
DBHOST=localhost
```

When I'm running `sudo automysqlbackup`, it's says access denied

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

It's still using root as username, but I set username as `tutor_db`. I wonder how to configure automysqlbackup.